# Putting user-defined on a list in for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop, user-defined-functions

I have problems storing user defined functions in R list when they are put on it in a for loop.

I have to define some segment-specific functions based on some parameters, so I create functions and put them on a list looping through segments with for-loop. The problem is I get same function everywhere on a result list.

The code looks like this:

```
n <- 100
segmenty <- 1:n
segment_functions <- list()
for (i in segmenty){
   segment_functions[[i]] <- function(){return(i)}
}
```

When i run the code what I get is the same function (last created in the loop) for all indexes:

```
## for all k
segment_functions[[k]]()
[1] 100
```

There is no problem when I put the functions on list manually e.g.

```
   segment_functions[[1]] <- function(){return(1)}
   segment_functions[[2]] <- function(){return(2)}
   segment_functions[[3]] <- function(){return(3)}
```

works just fine.

I honsetly have no idea what's wrong. Could you help?

Comment: You've almost exactly recreated the example at the bottom of the `?force` help page, which shows how to get it to work as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `force` function to ensure that the evaluation of `i` is done during the assignment into the list:

```
n <- 100
segmenty <- 1:n
segment_functions <- list()

f <- function(i) { force(i); function() return(i) }

for (i in segmenty){
  segment_functions[[i]] <- f(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `lapply` and capture `i` in a clousre of the wrapper:

```
segment_functions <- lapply(1:100, function(i) function() i)
```